# Identifying user by JWT Token?

Tags: php, security, jwt, token, privacy

I would like to use JWT Tokens for making sure that the request is send by an Android application. Therefore I send a POST request at the login to the server (PHP) and the server returns a JWT Token which is stored on the Android device. For the rest of the communication with the API, I would send the JWT Token with the request to make sure that the API request is permitted. However I am not sure how I could identify the user.

What is the recommended way to identify a user? I am not sure if it would be good to store the user id in a JWT Token as a payload. What would be the best way with regard to privacy concerns?

Comment: What are the "privacy concerns" exactly? JWT is a mechanism to store any claims you want (be it a user id or any other information you need).

Comment: So it is not a problem that a signed in user might decode the base64 JWT token so that the user knows its id?

Comment: What *would* be the consequence of that? If the user can do something in your system with that id that they wouldn't be able to do without knowing that id, then your security is weird.

Comment: The user can do nothing. That is why I would use this for identification. But I have read that this is not the best practice.

Comment: "not the best practice" --- "best practice" is very often just someone's preference.

Answer (score -1):

**Edit** : I said bullshit (see comments) :)

> What I (thought I was) usually doing is :
>
> - Client makes a login request
>
>   - Server creates a JWT associated with the corresponding user
>   - Server stores it, associated to the corresponding user
>   - Server sends it back to the client
>   - Client stores the JWT
> - Client makes an api call to query a resource, with the JWT
>
>   - Server authenticates the user (as the one which is linked to this JWT)
>   - Server do authorization checks for this user and this ressource
>   - Server appropriately do actions and send ressources
>
> In that way you don't need to store the user id in the JWT itself.

However, I agree with above comments : I'm not sure how the fact that user know their id might be a *privacy* concern. And if it is any how a *security* concern, then it's not only a concern, it's a security hole.

Comment: "Server stores it, associated to the corresponding user" --- server stores _what_? If you store the JWT on the server in full, do you really need JWT at all.

Comment: @zerkms: You are right. JWT should be an alternative to store it in a database.

Comment: @zerkms Mmmmm... In fact I was sure that was what the library I use did. But now I'm doubting.

Comment: @Pierre-OlivierVares if all you explained is valid - one invented sessions and then better* used a random session id, than jwt.